# Cocos2dx 2 порт с win32 на android

Tags: android, cocos2d

Чтобы сделать порт готового приложения win32 в android, нужно, как я понял, переименовать готовый win32 проект, создать проект android скриптом с таким же именем, взять оттуда папку `proj.android`, положить ее в папку готового проекта, удалить новую папку приложения, переименовать старую. Выполнить `build_native.sh`, после открыть проект еклипсом, и построить его. Но вот `build_native` не хочет ничего делать!

[image]

Comment: Так он же пишет ошибки. Или это нулевой проект?

Comment: Проект под win32, сделанный по туториалу с сайта cocos2dx, под win32 запускается нормально. Я не могу понять что это за ошибка. Создается файл еще какой то в папке obj, про который написано(main.o.d.org)

Comment: Если кто либо смог портировать с win32 приложение в android - скиньте линк на инструкцию, а то гугл не поддается.

Comment: скорее всего где-то проблемы с компилированием или же компилятор(или линковщик) не были найдены. Вообщем, надо настройки среды компилирования покопать или сам скрипт сборки может содержать просто неверные пути

Comment: Я создал сейчас новый проект Андроид скриптом, и копи-пастом пробовал менять поэтапно helloworld.cpp и helloworld.h, но вот при первом добавлении void( это как раз void HelloWorld::spriteMoveFinished(CCNode* sender); - что на скриншоте) вылазит писаная ошибка. В скрипте сборки 3 пути, так? Все 3 настроены точно, без этого скрипт сборки не запустится, Java_path прописан, а может быть из -того что последний NDK стоит?

Comment: Ну вот, надо было убрать HelloWorld:: перед объявлением и получить новые ошибки. Теперь member GameOverScene not declareted in Scope.
И где этот declarate осуществлять?

Comment: Моя опечатка, все ок теперь. Сложновато в этом разбираться.